# prepareForSegue is never called in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview, segue

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to perform a segue from my CollectionView but the prepareForSegue is never triggered when touching a Cell. This is working for my TableView but it's not for my CollectionView.

As you can see in my code, I have both in the same ViewController, but I don't know why it's only working for the TableView. The "segueCollection" is never triggered.

What I have to do in order to make this work? There is some type of problem because I'm also using the TableView segue? I'm a little bit lost here.

Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMovieFromTable", let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MovieViewController, index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
        destination.year = searchMovies[index].year
    } else if segue.identifier == "showMovieFromCollection" {
        print("segueCollection")
    }
    print("segueTriggered")
}
```

I'm also trying inside this code (but it's also not showing anything):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMovieFromCollection", sender: self)
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: "What I have to do in order to make this work?" yes let us know. how do you have attached segue to collection

Comment: I @Lu_, I have connected the "selection" option from the Cell inside the CollectionViewCell to the MovieViewController in the Storyboard.

Comment: Where do you call it (`performSegue:())`? How did you set it? For instance, if you put the segue directly from the cell to the next VC and not the current vc to the next vc, it won't be called.

Comment: Hi @Larme, I have updated my first post with the place where I call performSegue and it still not showing anything.

Comment: provide us a screenshot, with connnection in collection view cell and tableview cell you probalby make something different

Comment: Do you see any warnings in console. When performSegueWithIdentifier is called??

Comment: Hi @AhmadIshfaq, I haven't got any errors or warnings because is not called. I keep touching the cells and there isn't any message or warning at all.

Comment: Did you set the delegate? Is even `collectionView(collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` called?

Comment: It means that did didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not getting called correct??

Comment: I have set the delegates, but maybe the problem is that TableView also has the delegates in this ViewController. Could be this the problem?

Comment: Yes @AhmadIshfaq, it's not called.

Comment: No tableview delegates cannot be the problem.

Comment: Are their any subviews in collectionview cell that the user can interact with e.g button??

Comment: didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called when none of the subView of collectionViewCell respond to that touch.

Comment: Hi @AhmadIshfaq, no, I only have the Cell and it contains a single image. In the same position I have the tableView, may it's because it's like I'm touching the table instead of the collectionView even if the tableView is set to hidden?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118812/discussion-between-ahmad-ishfaq-and-jordi).

Comment: You can post the solution @AhmadIshfaq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and got stuck there for a bit time. Finally I realize, instead of using prepareForSegue, I have to use prepare function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
        // stuff you want to do
    }
}
```